# C++ headers - separation between interface and implementation details

Tags: c++, coding-style

One of classes in my program uses some third-party library. Library object is a private member of my class:

```
// My.h
    #include <3pheader.h>

    class My 
    {
    ...
    private:
       3pObject m_object;
    }
```

The problem with this - any other unit in my program that uses My class should be configured to include 3p headers. Moving to another kind of 3p will jeopardize the whole build...
I see two ways to fix this - one is to is to make 3pObject extern and turn m_Object into a pointer, being initialized in constructor; second is to create an "interface" and "factory" classes and export them...

Could you suggest another ways to solve that ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the "pimpl" idiom:

```
// header
class My
{
  class impl;
  std::auto_ptr<impl> _impl;
};

// cpp
#include <3pheader.h>
class My::impl
{
  3pObject _object;
};
```

Comment: Any reason not to use boost::scoped_ptr?

Comment: Nothing specific - I've been accustomed to using auto_ptr - it is probably more appropriate in this case to use scoped_ptr since there is no transfer of ownership

Answer (score 13):

The Private Implementation (PIMPL) pattern:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/PIMPL.aspx

Basically, you define that your class holds a pointer to a struct that you forward declare. Then you define the struct inside the cpp file and use the constructor and destructor in your class to create/delete the PIMPL.

:)

Answer (score 0):

All of the internal structure of [QT](http://trolltech.com/products) is done using private implementation classes.
You can look it up for a good reference on how it is done correctly.